# How to change dynamically host and port in mongodb url

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I tried to set dynamically change host and port in mongodb url but its not working. Can anybody give some suggestion? How to set host and port in mongodb url?

mongodb_url.js

```
host="localhost"
port="27017"
user ="root"
password = "mongodb"
let url = "mongodb://{user}:{password}@{localhost}:{port}";
```

url is not working how to set correctly using mongodb and node js

Comment: You are trying to use [template literal strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). Reference this for the correct syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use template literals as per es6 try wrapping with ` (backtick) instead of " (quotes)
like so:

```
let url = `mongodb://${user}:${password}@${host}:${port}`;
```

(note that it's 'host' not  'localhost' as per your definition)